# white dot texture issue in visual-studio-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

these white dot texture started appearing in my vs code suddenly and these dots keeps on appearing and disappearing with every click and it is distracting

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code version: 1.70.1. Try this in the menu.

```
View > Render Whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but didn't work. I was only able to resolve it by using a white theme rather than the dark theme.
File> Preferences > Theme > Color Theme > Light

Note: It still appears, but it blends with the color such that it's not noticeable.